# Implement query in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a query .

```
Select *
from table Temp
where (sender = :sender And reciever=:reciever)OR(sender = :reciever And reciever=:sender).
```

Can we write its equivalent query in JPQL?
I don't want to write a native query for this. Need to write a custom function that will generate a query internally.Like : use of findBy something

Comment: you can write it in native query, ex
@Query("select u from User u")
Stream<User> findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();

Comment: Where is your entity for that table? because nobody can tell you the answer until you do, since JPQL uses class/field names

Answer (score 1):

You can write a native query just like the following:

```
@Query(value="Select * from table Temp where (sender = :sender And reciever=:reciever)OR(sender = :reciever And reciever=:sender)", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Temp> getMatching(@Param("sender") String sender, @Param("reciever") String reciever);
```

Comment: I don't want to write a native query for this. Need to write a custom function that will generate a query internally.Like : use of findBy something

Answer (score 1):

Nothing strage in this query you can do something simple like this (though you didn't post any entities, so i had to guess the fields)

```
@Query("select t from Temp t where (t.sender = :sender and t.reciever=:reciever) OR (t.sender = :reciever and t.reciever=:sender)")
public List<Temp> methodName(@Param("sender") String sender, @Param("reciever") String reciever);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `EntityManager em`

```
public List<Temp> findBySenderReceiver(Sender sender, Receiver receiver) {    
    String jpql = "FROM Temp t WHERE (t.sender = :sender AND t.receiver = :receiver) OR (t.sender = :receiver AND t.receiver = :sender)";

    return em.createQuery(sql, Temp.class)
            .setParameter("sender", sender)
            .setParameter("receiver", receiver)
            .getResultList(); //or single result as you want
}
```